# Error while running program "Segmentation fault core dumped"

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to study pointers and functions, so I decided to write a simple code. But I have a problem with variable of the new type SIGNAL.
Every time when code is running, I have that mistake core dumped.
I tried to rewrite code, but is still the same mistake. I think that problem with data types, which I try to send to the signalD.
But I can't find out where I'm wrong.

I tried to send another data types and played with functions, but still the same result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*FUNC) (void*);
typedef FUNC (*SIGNAL) (int p, FUNC i);

void task1()
{
    printf("Run task 1\n");
}
void task2()
{
    printf("Run task 2\n");
}


 void mainProcess(SIGNAL signalD, int i, void *p,void (*f)(void*))
{
    task1();
    signalD(p,f)(i);//I'm afraid that here is a mistake with data  maybe (p,f)(f)
    printf("Run main process\n");
}

void task3()
{
    printf("Run task 3\n");
}

int main()
{
   mainProcess(task2,5,0,task3);
   return 0;
}
```

Program crashes when it goes to execute the signalD part.
I expect that it should print:
Run task 1
Run task 2
Run main process

Comment: `task2` is not taking any arguments (or to be precise their number/type is not specified), but you try to pass it something. Same with other "tasks" - define them with proper signatures..

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task2 function needs to return a `FUNC` doesn't it?

```
FUNC task2(int i, FUNC p)
{
    printf("Run task 2\n");
    return p;    
}
```

Also I think you want to call it like this;

```
signalD(i,f)(p);
```

You're compiler is giving you warnings for a reason, correct them and you can arrive at some fixes for your code.

Comment: Thank you, you gave good answer. Now I will study how that code is running in a right way.